# Copy files from S3 bucket to EC2 Windows Instance using Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I have uploaded design files (like images/css/js) to an S3 bucket and now I need to copy such files from the S3 bucket to an EC2 Windows instance whenever they are uploaded to/deleted from the bucket. I have created a Lambda function with a Powershell script but I don't see any way to access the EC2 instance and copy the files there. I tried the following script but I am seeing an error like `Cannot find drive. A drive with the name 'C' does not exist`

```
Start-EC2Instance -InstanceIds i-********
foreach ($i in Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Windows")
{
Write-Host $i.FullName  

}
```

Can someone please help on this.

Comment: The Lambda function runs in the cloud, not on the E2 instance. It has no access to the EC2 instance.

Comment: You might want to run commands against the instance id - using ssm  - something like this: $cancelCommandResponse=Send-SSMCommand -InstanceId @('Instance-ID','Instance-ID') -DocumentName AWS-RunPowerShellScript -Comment 'Demo AWS-RunPowerShellScript with two instances' -Parameter @{'commands'='Start-Sleep –Seconds 120; dir C:\'} --refer: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/walkthrough-powershell.html --- you can embed your commands - that should run 'inside' the instance in a series of commands to -Parameter @{'commands'='first-command';'second-command'}

Answer (score 0):

I use below pattern for a similar use case. In my case I want to run a powershell script on a newly created EC2 instance.

Ec2 instance (Windows) created -> CloudWatch event detects it -> Triggers Lambda Function -> Lambda Function runs an SSM document (it could very well be just SSM run commands like Ketanbhut suggested) -> SSM document runs the powershell script on the EC2 instance

In your case:
Upload file to S3 -> S3 event notification (you need to configure this) triggers Lambda function -> Lambda Function runs an SSM document -> SSM document runs the powershell script on the EC2 instance